# JMS Queue not receiving messages with ActiveMQ

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic

So I have used Spring integration to link JMS and ActiveMQ as under:-

```
<amq:broker useJmx="false" persistent="false">
    <amq:transportConnectors>
        <amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:0" />
    </amq:transportConnectors>
</amq:broker>

<bean id="amqConnectionFactory"  class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"  p:brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616"/>

<bean id="destination" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" c:name="destination"/> 

<bean id="testTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate" depends-on="amqConnectionFactory" scope="prototype"
      p:connectionFactory-ref="amqConnectionFactory"
      p:pubSubDomain="false"
      p:defaultDestination-ref="destination"
      p:sessionTransacted="true"
      p:receiveTimeout="5000"/>
```

Now, when I run the test by starting ActiveMQ and then running my application, I see that the messages are published to the "destination" queue from the logs. However, I am not able to retrieve any of these from the queue. Even in JConsole, it shows the queueSize and counts as 0.

How do I make it work so that I can send to and receives messages from this queue? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you specify the transport connector to: `tcp://localhost:0` and the ConnectionFactory URL to `tcp://localhost:61616`?

I would use the same URL for both.